# Keyword IF not expected

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, rowcount

I have the following inline SQL code, running on an AS400.  The IF comes up as unexpected but I don't understand why.  What I'm trying to do is to build a stored procedure to update, or insert, a table row. The code shown below is inline to ensure my logic is correct.

I've tried a number of different approaches including IF EXISTS, CASE, SET @COUNT = SELECT COUNT(*).  I continue to run into odd errors.

In the code shown below, I fail when I hit the IF statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE IN_LOC         CHAR(02);     
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE IN_MCO         CHAR(02);     
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE IN_SYMBOL      CHAR(03); 
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE IN_POLICYNUM   CHAR(07); 
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE IN_MODULE      CHAR(02); 
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE IN_RISKLOC     CHAR(05); 
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE IN_PRCCLASS    VARCHAR(05); 
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE IN_PRCTER      VARCHAR(03); 
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE IN_MESSAGE     CHAR(02); 
    
SET IN_LOC='00';    
SET IN_MCO='01';    
SET IN_SYMBOL='CPP';    
SET IN_POLICYNUM='0003748'; 
SET IN_MODULE='00'; 
SET IN_RISKLOC='00003'; 
SET IN_PRCCLASS='09';   
SET IN_PRCTER='1';  
SET IN_MESSAGE='NOT FOUND FOR ODD PROGRAMMING';

UPDATE BASPPRC01
    SET PRCCLASS=IN_PRCCLASS,PRCTER=IN_PRCTER,MESSAGE=IN_MESSAGE
WHERE CAST(IN_LOC||IN_MCO||IN_SYMBOL||IN_POLICYNUM||IN_MODULE||IN_RISKLOC AS CHAR(21))
    = CAST(LOCATION||MASTERCO||SYMBOL||POLICYNUM||MODULE||RISKLOC AS CHAR(21)) ;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BASPPRC01
        (LOCATION,MASTERCO,SYMBOL,POLICYNUM,MODULE,RISKLOC,PRCCLASS,PRCTER,MESSAGE)
    VALUES
        (IN_LOC
        , IN_MCO
        , IN_SYMBOL
        , IN_POLICYNUM
        , IN_MODULE
        , IN_RISKLOC
        , IN_PRCCLASS
        , IN_PRCTER
        , IN_MESSAGE ) ;
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
```

Comment: inline of what?  The code you show isn't a valid `CREATE PROCEDURE`  nor a valid compound statement in Access Client Solutions (ACS) "Run SQL Scripts".  Finally, you should consider doing such an "Upsert" with the `MERGE` statement....assuming you're actually using a modern POWER system running IBM i and not actually an AS/400.

Comment: Yes, we use a modern POWER system running IBM i and not an actual AS/400.  

Yes, this is not a valid CREATE.  It is the Run SQL Scripts option to execute interactive SQL code.

Why a MERGE?  There are many options to MERGE.  In this case, I did not see a MERGE statement as the most likely.  

The issue though is more why the code fails on the IF statement?  That "should" be okay to roll to that statement.  But, the code is flagged as unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should show the error you get...

with the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc ()
        LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
UPDATE BASPPRC01
    SET PRCCLASS=IN_PRCCLASS,PRCTER=IN_PRCTER,MESSAGE=IN_MESSAGE
WHERE CAST(IN_LOC||IN_MCO||IN_SYMBOL||IN_POLICYNUM||IN_MODULE||IN_RISKLOC AS CHAR(21))
    = CAST(LOCATION||MASTERCO||SYMBOL||POLICYNUM||MODULE||RISKLOC AS CHAR(21)) ;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO BASPPRC01
        (LOCATION,MASTERCO,SYMBOL,POLICYNUM,MODULE,RISKLOC,PRCCLASS,PRCTER,MESSAGE)
    VALUES
        (IN_LOC
        , IN_MCO
        , IN_SYMBOL
        , IN_POLICYNUM
        , IN_MODULE
        , IN_RISKLOC
        , IN_PRCCLASS
        , IN_PRCTER
        , IN_MESSAGE ) ;
END

COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
END;
```

I get `[SQL0199] Keyword BEGIN not expected. Valid tokens: THEN.`

This passes a syntax check, note `THEN` and `END IF` instead of `BEGIN` also, `COMMIT` instead of `COMMIT TRANSACTION`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure2 ()
        LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
UPDATE BASPPRC01
    SET PRCCLASS=IN_PRCCLASS,PRCTER=IN_PRCTER,MESSAGE=IN_MESSAGE
WHERE CAST(IN_LOC||IN_MCO||IN_SYMBOL||IN_POLICYNUM||IN_MODULE||IN_RISKLOC AS CHAR(21))
    = CAST(LOCATION||MASTERCO||SYMBOL||POLICYNUM||MODULE||RISKLOC AS CHAR(21)) ;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO BASPPRC01
        (LOCATION,MASTERCO,SYMBOL,POLICYNUM,MODULE,RISKLOC,PRCCLASS,PRCTER,MESSAGE)
    VALUES
        (IN_LOC
        , IN_MCO
        , IN_SYMBOL
        , IN_POLICYNUM
        , IN_MODULE
        , IN_RISKLOC
        , IN_PRCCLASS
        , IN_PRCTER
        , IN_MESSAGE ) ;
END IF;

COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you Charles.  I just could not see what syntax I had incorrect.  I appreciate the help!